# ¿C++ incapaz de crear un cuadro mágico de 4x4 con rand()?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

buenas noches.

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en C++. Nos pidieron crear un programa que sea capaz de crear un cuadro mágico de 3x3 y un cuadro mágico de 4x4. Por suerte, ya había visto a alguien hacer este ejercicio, así que seguí la misma ruta de la persona que lo resolvió: hacerlo usando rand() con comprobaciones lógicas por el camino para asegurar que el cada número no está en la matriz y al  final hacer las sumas respectivas para ver si la matriz representa un cuadro mágico o no.

El problema es que, por alguna razón, C++ pareciera incapaz de generar un cuadro mágico de 4x4 siguiendo el siguiente proceso, que es el mismo que usé para el cuadro de 3x3.

Haciendo pruebas vi que es capaz de crear cuadros que, o sumen en todas sus filas 34, o sumen en todas sus columnas 34, o sumen en sus diagonales 34, pero en cuanto le pido cumplir al menos dos de esas condiciones, ya no puede hacerlo y se queda generando cuadros infinitamente. ¿A alguien se le ocurre cuál es el error de mi semántica o por qué sucede esto?

¿Hay forma de generar el cuadro por este método o debería buscar un método diferente?

Gracias por su atención.

Adjunto el código en cuestión:

```
//Declaro librerías
#include <iostream>                     //cout <<
#include <cstdlib>                      //srand()/rand()
#include <ctime>                        //time()

//Evito escribir std:: cada vez
using namespace std;

//Prototipo funciones
void format(int cuadro[4][4]);          //Asigna 0 a todos los elementos de la matriz
void crear(int cuadro[4][4]);           //Asigna un número diferente a cada elemento
bool check(int temp, int cuadro[4][4]); //Revisa si el número ya está en la matriz
bool nomagic(int cuadro[4][4]);         //Revisa si la matriz no es un cuadro mágico
void mostrar(int cuadro[4][4]);         //Muestra la matriz

int main(){
    //Semilla aleatoria 
    srand(time('\0'));
    
    //Declaración de varibles
    int cuadro[4][4]={0};
    
    //Generación del cuadro
    do{
        format(cuadro);
        crear(cuadro);
    }while(nomagic(cuadro));
    
    //Impresión de datos
    mostrar(cuadro);
            
    cin.ignore();
    
    return 0;
}

//Desarollo funciones
void format(int cuadro[4][4]){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)              //Se repite para cada elemento de la matriz
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            cuadro[i][j]=0;             //Asigna 0 al elemento
}

void crear(int cuadro[4][4]){
    int temp=0;                         //Crea un número temporal
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)              //Se repite para cada elemento de la matriz
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            do
                temp=rand()%16+1;       //Asigna un número aleatorio entre 1 y 16
            while(check(temp, cuadro)); //Revisa si el número ya está en la matriz
            cuadro[i][j]=temp;          //Asigna el número al elemento
        }
}

bool check(int temp, int cuadro[4][4]){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)          //Se repite para cada elemento de la matriz
            if(temp==cuadro[i][j])      //Compara el número con el elemento
                return 1;               //Si son el mismo, devuelve 1.
    return 0;                           //Si no encuentra el número, devuelve 0.
}

bool nomagic(int cuadro[4][4]){
    int sum=0;                          //Crea una variable para la sumatoria
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){             //Se repite para cada fila de la matriz
        sum=0;                          //Reinicia la sumatoria
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)          //Se repite para cada elemento de la fila
            sum+=cuadro[i][j];          //Suma el valor del elemento a la sumatoria
        if(sum!=34)
            return 1;                   //Si no suman 34, devuelve 1.
    }
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){             //Se repite para cada columna de la matriz
        sum=0;
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)          //Se repite para cada elemento de la columna
            sum+=cuadro[j][i];
        if(sum!=34)
            return 1;
    }
    sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)              //Se repite para cada elemento de la diagonal
        sum+=cuadro[i][i];
    if(sum!=34)
        return 1;
    sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)              //Se repite para cada elemento de la diagonal
        sum+=cuadro[i][3-i];            //complemento a 3 para invertir las filas
    if(sum!=34)
        return 1;
    return 0;                           //Si todo suma 34, regresa 0. 
}

void mostrar(int cuadro[4][4]){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){             //Se repite para fila de la matriz
        cout <<" ";                     //Imprime un cuadro de sangría
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){         //Se repite para cada elelemento de la fila
            if(cuadro[i][j]<10)         //Se imprime un espacio antes de los elementos mayores a
                cout <<" ";             //10 para mantener la cuadrícula.
            cout <<cuadro[i][j]<<" ";   //Imprime el elemento seguido de un espacio
        }
        cout <<endl;                    //Salta línea al terminar la fila.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No he repasado tu código, pero asumiendo que no hayas introducido algún bug al redimensionar el cuadrado, lo que veo es que el algoritmo "funciona" pero no ha encontrado un cuadrado mágico, por dos cuestiones no excluyentes:

#### No has tenido suerte.

Con las cosas aleatorias es lo que pasa. Igual el primer cuadrado generado es mágico y acaba en unos milisegundos, igual el programa está probando millones de cuadrados que son inválidos y no acaba.

#### Las probabilidades son mucho menores

Con tácticas de fuerza bruta (probar valores hasta que uno funciona) los tiempos de respuesta pueden alargarse muchísimo si el tamaño del problema cambia. Así que conviene documentarse.

Para un cuadrado de 3x3, [hay un único cuadrado mágico](https://www.gaussianos.com/cuadrados-magicos/)<sup>1</sup>, para uno de 4x4, 880.

Pero hay 9! = 362880 posibles formas de organizar los números del 1 al 9 en un cuadrado de 3x3, y 16! = 2.092279e+13, más de 20 billones de formas de organizar los números del 1 al 16 en un cuadrado de 4x4.

Es decir, la probabilidad de que un cuadrado de 3x3 aleatorio sea mágico es proporcional<sup>2</sup> a 1/362880. La probabilidad de que un cuadrado de 4x4 aleatorio sea mágico es proporcional a 880/2.092279e+13 que aproximadamente es 1/23775897600. Es decir, es como 65.000 veces más improbable.

Además de que de media necesitarás generar más cuadrados de 4x4 para encontrar uno mágico, para generar un cuadrado 4x4 tienes que hacer muchas más operaciones (generar más números, comprobar que los números generados no estén ya en el cuadrado) así que cada prueba es más lenta.

Por eso tu programa se queda sin responderte, porque todavía no ha encontrado un cuadrado mágico.

La respuesta correcta es usar un algoritmo mejor para generar cuadrados mágicos.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hay que multiplicar por posibles rotaciones y reflexiones.

<sup>2</sup>De nuevo porque hay que contar rotaciones y reflexiones.

Comment: Waoo, ¡jamás habría imaginado que las cosas escalarían tanto por añadir añadir una columna y una fila! Claro que pensé que se tardaría más, pero como al de 3x3 no le toma un segundo, y éste lo dejé corriendo minutos, asumí que no funcionaba.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿A alguien se le ocurre cuál es el error de mi semántica o por qué sucede esto?

Tienes una matriz de 4x4 y la rellenas aleatoriamente con números del 1 al 16, para una fila o columna cualquiera esto suponen 16^4=65536 combinaciones diferentes. Éstas combinaciones ofrecerán sumas que van del 4 al 64, siendo el valor medio, 34, que es el que buscas... estadísticamente es el más probable, pero que sea el más probable no implica que sea un valor seguro. Concretamente la probabilidad de obtener 34 es del 3.14%. Y eso para una fila o columna. (hay que tener en cuenta que no puede haber dos números iguales)

Para que todas las columnas sumen 34 la probabilidad es aún más baja, dado que son sucesos independientes la probabilidad aquí es inferior a 0.00009721%

Si ya seguimos añadiendo condiciones, como que la suma de las 4 columnas y las 2 diagonales sumen igualmente 34, la probabilidad resultante resulta ínfima.

Este no es el camino para encontrar una solución ... puede que en algún momento después de años de cálculo consigas dar con una solución, pero desde luego no es un mecanismo práctico.

Puedes intentar construir tu algoritmo generador de números mágicos aplicando las matemáticas.

Podemos empezar por asignarle a cada celda del cuadrado una letra:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

Con esto obtenemos las siguientes ecuaciones:

```
a + b + c + d = 34
e + f + g + h = 34
i + j + k + l = 34
m + n + o + p = 34
a + e + i + m = 34
b + f + j + n = 34
c + g + k + o = 34
d + h + l + p = 34
a + f + k + p = 34
d + g + j + m = 34
```

El sistema tiene 16 incógitas y 10 ecuaciones, luego existen infinitas soluciones al problema. El número de soluciones se reduce si añadimos la restricción de que los valores de las variables deben estar en el rango 1-16

Si ahora juegas con estas ecuaciones podrás relacionar unas variables con otras, de tal forma que la creación del cuadrado sea trivial, por ejemplo:

```
a+e b+f c+g d+h
c+h d+g a+f b+e
d+f c+e b+h a+g
b+g a+h d+e c+f
```

Ahora simplemente hay que asignar valores a cada variable (cuidando que la suma total de 34) y ya tendrás tu cuadrado mágico, por ejemplo:

```
a = 0
b = -1
c = 8
d = 7
e = 2
f = 6
g = 4
h = 8
```

Lo que nos daría el siguiente cuadrado mágico:

```
 2  5 12 15
16 11  6  1
13 10  7  4
 3  8  9 14
```

La solución se podría refinar para tus intereses, yo solamente me limito a mostrarte una posible salida a tu problema

Comment: Gracias, intentaré seguir este camino para buscar mi solución.